# How to scrape multiple products on Google Shopping with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Following [this](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-shopping-with-python-49ad) article, I created my first web **scraper** with Python. My intention is to scrape Google Shopping, looking for products price. The script works, but I want to search more than one product when I run the script.

So, I'm looping over a list of products like this:

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from dataProducts import products

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

stores = ["Submarino", "Casas Bahia", "Extra.com.br", "Americanas.com", 
"Pontofrio.com", "Shoptime", "Magazine Luiza", "Amazon.com.br - Retail", "Girafa"]

products = [
    {
        "name" : "Console Playstation 5",
        "lowestPrice" : 4000.0,
        "highestPrice" : 4400.0
    },
    {
        "name" : "Controle Xbox Robot",
        "lowestPrice" : 320.0,
        "highestPrice" : 375.0
    }
]

for product in products:
    params = {"q": product["name"], 'tbm': 'shop'}

    response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search",
                            params=params,
                            headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    # Normal results
    for shopping_result in soup.select('.sh-dgr__content'):
        product = shopping_result.select_one('.Lq5OHe.eaGTj h4').text
        price = shopping_result.select_one('span.kHxwFf span.a8Pemb').text
        store = shopping_result.select_one('.IuHnof').text
        link = f"https://www.google.com{shopping_result.select_one('.Lq5OHe.eaGTj')['href']}"

        if store in stores:
            print(product)
            print(price)
            print(store)
            print(link)
            print()
            print()
    print('####################################################################################################################################################')
```

When I run the script, it doesn't bring all the data. And sometimes, It doesn't even bring any data from the first search. It just show the prints from the second iteration. I tried to put a sleed after the soup line, 10 seconds, after last line of the loop, and nothing changes.

I don't understang why my script can't get all the results for the given products. Can anyone give me a little help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the articles you've shared and the script was most likely outdated due to frequent changes on Google's side (CSS selectors change or something else).

[I've updated the blog post](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-google-shopping-tab-in-python/#fullcode) with new code (have a look at the `suggested_search_data()` function:

```py
import requests, json, re, os
from parsel import Selector # instead of beautifulsoup

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "shoes",
    "hl": "en",     # language
    "gl": "us",     # country of the search, US -> USA
    "tbm": "shop"   # google search shopping
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
selector = Selector(html.text)


def get_original_images():
    all_script_tags = "".join(
        [
            script.replace("</script>", "</script>\n")
            for script in selector.css("script").getall()
        ]
    )
    
    image_urls = []
    
    for result in selector.css(".Qlx7of .sh-dgr__grid-result"):
        # https://regex101.com/r/udjFUq/1
        url_with_unicode = re.findall(rf"var\s?_u='(.*?)';var\s?_i='{result.attrib['data-pck']}';", all_script_tags)

        if url_with_unicode:
            url_decode = bytes(url_with_unicode[0], 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
            image_urls.append(url_decode)
            
    # download_original_images(image_urls)  
    
    return image_urls


def download_original_images(image_urls):
    for index, image_url in enumerate(image_urls, start=1):
        image = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers, timeout=30, stream=True)
    
        if image.status_code == 200:
            print(f"Downloading {index} image...")
            with open(f"images/image_{index}.jpeg", "wb") as file:
                file.write(image.content)


def get_suggested_search_data():
    google_shopping_data = []
    
    for result, thumbnail in zip(selector.css(".i0X6df"), get_original_images()):
        title = result.css(".tAxDx::text").get()    
        product_link = "https://www.google.com" + result.css(".Lq5OHe::attr(href)").get()   
        product_rating = result.css(".NzUzee .Rsc7Yb::text").get()      
        product_reviews = result.css(".NzUzee > div::text").get()       
        price = result.css(".a8Pemb::text").get()       
        store = result.css(".aULzUe::text").get()       
        store_link = "https://www.google.com" + result.css(".eaGTj div a::attr(href)").get()        
        delivery = result.css(".vEjMR::text").get()
        
        store_rating_value = result.css(".zLPF4b .XEeQ2 .QIrs8::text").get()
        # https://regex101.com/r/kAr8I5/1
        store_rating = re.search(r"^\S+", store_rating_value).group() if store_rating_value else store_rating_value
        
        store_reviews_value = result.css(".zLPF4b .XEeQ2 .ugFiYb::text").get()
        # https://regex101.com/r/axCQAX/1
        store_reviews = re.search(r"^\(?(\S+)", store_reviews_value).group() if store_reviews_value else store_reviews_value

        store_reviews_link_value = result.css(".zLPF4b .XEeQ2 .QhE5Fb::attr(href)").get()
        store_reviews_link = "https://www.google.com" + store_reviews_link_value if store_reviews_link_value else store_reviews_link_value

        compare_prices_link_value = result.css(".Ldx8hd .iXEZD::attr(href)").get()      
        compare_prices_link = "https://www.google.com" + compare_prices_link_value if compare_prices_link_value else compare_prices_link_value

        google_shopping_data.append({
            "title": title,
            "product_link": product_link,
            "product_rating": product_rating,
            "product_reviews": product_reviews,
            "price": price,
            "store": store,
            "thumbnail": thumbnail,
            "store_link": store_link,
            "delivery": delivery,
            "store_rating": store_rating,
            "store_reviews": store_reviews,
            "store_reviews_link": store_reviews_link,
            "compare_prices_link": compare_prices_link,
        })

    print(json.dumps(google_shopping_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    
get_suggested_search_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

To start off I would recommend selenium requests will most times not bring data. Second if you are trying to get alerts for stock for PS5's or Xbox's I would scrape a website not google. You will need to install chrome and chrome driver. Link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads Below is how to use Selenium!

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

ua = UserAgent()
options = Options()
options.add_argument("useragent="+ua.random)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver location", options=options)

browser.get("https://google.com")
html = browser.page_source
```

So you need to do:
`pip install selenium`
`pip install fake_useragent` to get it setup.
Then using `html` you can use BS4 to scrape the website.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand why I should use selenium. The thing is that google shopping is like a summary for what I want. If I go on every store, looking for every product, is gonna be a lot harder to implement the script.